# Error in Spring XML schema "No setter found for property 'oAuth2RequestValidator'"

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, xsd-validation

I have an error in my Spring file ' authorization-server-custom-grant. xml', about a setter that you are not in the class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint, which inherits or is the son of org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.

This is my file XML authorization-server-custom-grant.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">
    <bean id="tokenGranter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.xml.AuthorizationServerCustomGrantParserTests.CustomTestTokenGranter" />
    <oauth2:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails">
        <oauth2:authorization-code />
        <oauth2:custom-grant token-granter-ref="tokenGranter" />
    </oauth2:authorization-server>
    <oauth2:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth2:client client-id="foo" authorized-grant-types="password"/>
    </oauth2:client-details-service>
</beans>
```

And eclipse displays this error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - No setter found for property 'oAuth2RequestFactory' in class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint'
    - No setter found for property 'oAuth2RequestValidator' in class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint'
    - No setter found for property 'oAuth2RequestFactory' in class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint'
    - No setter found for property 'oAuth2RequestValidator' in class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint'
```

this is my file pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
<name>OAuth2 for Spring Security</name>
<description>Module for providing OAuth2 support to Spring Security</description>

<properties>
    <jackson1.version>1.9.13</jackson1.version>
    <jackson2.version>2.3.2</jackson2.version>
    <spring.security.jwt.version>1.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.jwt.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/schema" />
                            <copy todir="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/schema">
                                <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
                                    <include name="**/*.xsd" />
                                </fileset>
                                <mapper type="flatten" />
                            </copy>

                            <copy file="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/schema/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd" tofile="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/schema/spring-security-oauth2.xsd" />

                            <zip destfile="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/sparklr2.zip">
                                <zipfileset dir="../samples/oauth2/sparklr" includes="pom.xml src/**" prefix="sparklr" />
                            </zip>
                            <zip destfile="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/tonr2.zip">
                                <zipfileset dir="../samples/oauth2/tonr" includes="pom.xml src/**" prefix="tonr" />
                            </zip>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <!-- In case we test with Spring 4 -->
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!--for the annotations. -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!--for the annotations. -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!--for the annotations. -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!--for the annotations. -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson1.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson2.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson2.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb-j5</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orange.redis-embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the java source file(which occurs in the error message), find the setter method for the field, delete it and re-generate it using eclipse menu: Source-> Generate Getters and Setters.

Looks like the signature for the setter method can't be recognized by eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Just clean and build project from the menu bar.

Comment: If the setter is present, this will likely solve your issue.